# Submitting an iOS app with a pre-release version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

We found some bugs in our iOS app when running in iOS 7.1 (which is currently in beta).

The bugs were fixed using pre-release version of Xcode 5.1 and the iOS 7.1 beta SDK.

Now, we want to submit our iOS 7.1 ready app to the App Store.

Problem is that iTunes Connect rejects apps built with this version of Xcode/baseSDK.

Should we wait until Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1 is released to submit this version?

I was under the impression that the idea of a pre-release version of Xcode and iOS SDK is to fix your apps before that new iOS version is released.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an Apple tech support question and is not related to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only submit your prerelease fixes with the GM version of Xcode.
Beta is for developer devices, not for primary ones.

Similar question: [Submit App for iOS 7 Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747527/submit-app-for-ios-7-now)

Comment: Sounds good, we'll wait until Xcode 5.1 / iOS 7.1 enters the GM state to submit our iOS 7.1 ready app. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have to submit your app using the released version.  If it builds fine in Xcode 5, submit your project using that. If it doesn't, post the details of the issue you're having.

Apple sometimes offers developers the ability to submit updates a week or two before the iOS update comes out.